# How add/remove value to ActionController::Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

What is the best way add/remove value from ActionController::Parameters in Rails.
For example:

```
[96] pry(main)> params = ActionController::Parameters.new({controller: "home", action: 'index', prop1: "val"})
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"controller"=>"home", "action"=>"index", "prop1"=>"val"} permitted: false>
[97] pry(main)> my_params = params.permit(:prop1)
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>"val"} permitted: true>
[98] pry(main)> my_params.merge(prop1: "val2")
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>"val2"} permitted: true>
```

I need behavior like this:

```
# add
pry(main)> my_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>"val1"} permitted: true>
pry(main)> my_params.awesome_add(prop1: "val2")
<ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>["val1", "val2"]} permitted: true>
# remove
pry(main)> my_params.awesome_remove(prop1: "val1")
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>"val2"} permitted: true>
```

Comment: What awesome methods you are looking for doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to achieve in your actual application. We may fix the issue in other place.

Comment: ok, how generate path with query string for each scope in view (filter.erb.html) used gem has_scope without deleting the previous params?

Answer (score 0):

`Hash#merge` does not mutate the original. When you do this `params` does not change.

```
params.merge(key: "value")
```

The same is true of `ActionController::Parameters`:

```
my_params.merge(prop1: "val2")
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>"val2"} permitted: true>
```

If you want to use the result of that call, you should either use the bang method `merge!` to mutate `my_params` in place, or assign the result to a variable:

```
my_params = my_params.merge(some: "thing")
```

Comment: What OP want is .. update "string" value with an array and vice versa with some magic. That ofcourse pretty weird.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I disagree. He needs to modify the `params` in his controller and he's using methods that don't edit in place. Cheers tho.

Comment: What pattern you do see here?

`pry(main)> my_params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>"val1"} permitted: true>
pry(main)> my_params.awesome_add(prop1: "val2")
<ActionController::Parameters {"prop1"=>["val1", "val2"]} permitted: true>` What I see/read is that.. OP wants a magic method which turns `{"prop1"=>"val1"}` to `"prop1"=>["val1", "val2"]` .. where he will supply just `prop1: "val2"`. Here `merge` method is not tool and I don't know what tool out there without hand made something.